# Reusable UITableView for Varying Data Input - Swift/Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a TableView that I want to reuse for different categories of data (essentially as plugins.. the tableView being a skeleton and being filled with whatever I want it to be). The TableView is filled with different categories of data (and related actions) depending on essentially what ViewController the user came from. I understand how to make it display the various data (just send it whatever array I want it to display), but I can't figure out how I could control the actions for the data at the specific index selected in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

How could I do this? How could I create an array that has both Strings and executable actions associated with each indices? For example:

```
arrayOneNames = ["Tigris", "Leo", "Barko"]
arrayOneActions = [displayTheTigers, displayTheCats, displayTheDogs]
```

If "Leo" is selected in the tableView, then "displayTheCats" is executed. Again, I want each array to be a separate Class that I can use as a plugin, so that I can fill the tableView with whichever Class of data I want it to display and execute, depending on which ViewController the user came from previously. Please answer in Swift.

Comment: what if you pass a tag to tableviewcell depending on type and then inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath just check the tag and execute the relevant method?

Comment: That's a great idea! I was considering having a string that it checked (if string == "cats" then call displayTheCats), but tags seem more efficient.

Comment: How about using a `Cat` struct that has a `name` and an `action` as its properties. Then your array would store `Cat` objects and each cat object has a name and the associated action.

Comment: @WimukthiRajapaksha I tried this and it didn't work properly, btw. I'm not sure if I did something wrong or not, but I'm pretty sure I set it up correctly.

Comment: @ShawnFrank I'm going to give that a shot and see if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell=UITableViewCell() // cell you've created
    cell.data = arrayOneNames[indexPath.row] // passing relevant data
    cell.tag = indexPath.row // the tag you want to pass for particular data 
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell // take selected cell
    if(cell.tag == 0) { // call relevant function accordingly.
        self.tigrisTouch()
    } else if (cell.tag == 1) {
        self.leoTouch()
    } else {
        self.barkoTouch()
    }
}

private func tigrisTouch() {
}

private func leoTouch() {        
}

private func barkoTouch() {
}
```